# Web User Control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am written a User Control. in the User Control, There are Header and Footer.
i want insert gridview or any Control , in Content of the User control.
for a Example:
`<Menu:Menu id="1" runAt="Server">`
`<Asp:GridView ...> /// or any control`
`</Menu>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example to create your own Templated Controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178657.aspx

This way you can create a WebControl that can contain templates where you place any control.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ParseChildren attribute. Check [this](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/asp-net-controls-building/2271/Nested-controls-in-User-Control-via-ParseChildren) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx) posts.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Placeholder control.

```
<Menu:Menu id="1" runAt="Server">
    <asp:Placeholder id="phControl" runat="server" />
</Menu>
```

And in your code-behind:

```
TextBox myText = new TextBox();
phControl.Controls.Add(myText);
```

Comment: If you cannot put a control inside the usercontrol, you can't even put a placeholder there.